Question on Consent For Female Slaves in Islam
I see mixed messages on this.
I found one Hadith which seems to infer that consent is required.

حَدَّثَنِي مَالِكٌ، عَنْ نَافِعٍ، أَنَّ عَبْدًا، كَانَ يَقُومُ عَلَى
رَقِيقِ الْخُمُسِ وَأَنَّهُ اسْتَكْرَهَ جَارِيَةً مِنْ ذَلِكَ
الرَّقِيقِ فَوَقَعَ بِهَا فَجَلَدَهُ عُمَرُ بْنُ الْخَطَّابِ وَنَفَاهُ
وَلَمْ يَجْلِدِ الْوَلِيدَةَ لأَنَّهُ اسْتَكْرَهَهَا ‏.‏
Malik related to me from Nafi that a slave was in charge of the slaves
in the khumus and he forced a slave-girl among those slaves against
her will and had intercourse with her. Umar ibn al-Khattab had him
flogged and banished him, and he did not flog the slave-girl because
the slave had forced her.
Muwatta Malik https://sunnah.com/urn/515160

But the Quran and the rest of the Hadiths on this matter do not refer to consent at all. There is no mention of it.
Many Muslims will make an argument that because Muhammad said "do no harm" this would apply to sexual relations too and mean consent is required, but this is really stretching it.
Others say that because Muhammad ordered a slave freed because she was slapped, therefore consent is required for sex with a female slave.
What is the right interpretation?

I gave detailed answer below but if prophet peace and blessings be upon him gave a clear ruling not to harm the slaves: then how does forceful sex doesn't fall into that. Unless you say forceful sex doesn't fall under harm. Basic fiqh rule that that prophet told us is: don't harm yourself or other. So I don't understand your point as to how is that a Strach.

In the quoted hadith a slave was punished for zina, he was not permitted to have intercourse with the female slave as she was neither her wife nor concubine. The female slave was not punished for zina because she was forced. This hadith is irrelevant to the question you are asking.

@UmH So the hadith is only punishing the male slave for having sexual intercourse with a female slave because this female slave was not a wife/concubine, not because this male slave forced it on her?

@UmH I am asking this because of the notion of Muhammad saying "do no harm" and how it applies here. Because he said this, many extrapolate that this means consent is required in sexual relations with slaves because forcing such causes irreparable harm on the slave.
Because there is nothing mentioned of consent in this matter in the Quran or Hadith, the notion of "no harm" leaves an impression that consent is required because of their being no specific mention of the issue of consent.
The same argument is used for Muhammad freeing a slave because she was slapped.

what u trying to do is take the concept of consent of 21st century to 7th century. Word consent had different meaning in different time. Type of consent we see today didn't exist. Slave of those time, knew what thier role was. So matter of consent was not like it's today. I remeber in the 90s it wasn't even like it's in 2024. It's horror story out there like, 2 ppl had physical relationship and woman feels bad after wards so she says she can take back her consent and now it's rape etc. So if you are looking for consent of 2024 then I don't u will find it. 2nd, no harm covers basic of no harm.

It's on the concept of no harm. So a guy can't physically harm his slave, male or female. For example: guy can't severely beat his slave, or give impossible amt of work, or force female slave to prostitution or kill them etc. If one does that then there is non prescribed punishment given by judge based on evidence. So "no harm" covers all that.

@Juzernejm I understand what you are trying to figure out, but the punishment for rape is similar to fornication/adultery based on the marital status. So he did get punished for rape, normally both would get punished because it would have been consentual, since it's not, only one of them got punished since it won't be fair on the victim to get punished for something she has no fault in. For rape, sometimes other forms of punishment are also compounded such as an amount to be paid to the victim as compensation whether the victims are slaves or free.Sometimes the perpetrator is banished as well.

The thing about Consent is, you can't forcefully have your way with you wife or your concubine, although consent during that time wasn't the same as we know today, "No harm" principles covers all. Rape would fall under the category of harm. But people during that time when they became a wife/concubine, they knew their roles well and for concubines, they were well aware of their vulnerable position and had idea about their roles. It's either that to have a shelter, food, clothing, protection etc or do prostitution to survive. When you have to survive, you don't think the way you do normally.

Please read the Athar correctly first. It says:

Malik related to me from Nafi that a slave was in charge of the slaves in the khumus and he forced a slave-girl among those slaves against her will and had intercourse with her. Umar ibn al-Khattab had him flogged and banished him, and he did not flog the slave-girl because the slave had forced her.

So the subject and reason why the man was punished was Zina and he was a slave not a free man and neither the husband nor the owner of the slave-girl. He further was seemingly unmarried. And Allah ordered the punishment for this case in the qur'an:

The [unmarried] woman or [unmarried] man found guilty of sexual intercourse - lash each one of them with a hundred lashes, and do not be taken by pity for them in the religion of Allah , if you should believe in Allah and the Last Day. And let a group of the believers witness their punishment. (24:2)

In case the slave was married the punishment is also specified in the qur'an:

And whoever among you cannot [find] the means to marry free, believing women, then [he may marry] from those whom your right hands possess of believing slave girls. And Allah is most knowing about your faith. You [believers] are of one another. So marry them with the permission of their people and give them their due compensation according to what is acceptable. [They should be] chaste, neither [of] those who commit unlawful intercourse randomly nor those who take [secret] lovers. But once they are sheltered in marriage, if they should commit adultery, then for them is half the punishment for free [unmarried] women. This [allowance] is for him among you who fears sin, but to be patient is better for you. And Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.

So 'Umar ibn al-Khattab simply applied the punishment for Zina and since it was clear that the slave-girl was forced only the slave who forced her was punished.
However, at least imam Malik and imam a-Shafi'i didn't agree to banish such a wrongdoer.

Muwatta Malik is one of most authentic book in Islam. In term of authenticity its in lvl of bukhari and Muslim. But it contains reports of the companion and generation unlike bukhari and muslim which contains ahadith of the prophet peace and blessings be upon him.
But we follow the companions and 2 generation after them. As they are part of Salaf.
Now about the consent: to answer your question:
It doesn't mention in the Quran: Quran is kalam of Allah, it doesn't have to give everything to the t. It contains clear rulings, guidelines, history of the part and Prophecy of the future.
Hance we had the prophet peace and blessing be upon him, teaching us, explain to us. If quran said pray, prophet taught us how to pray. So if quran mentioned about "RIGHT HAND POSSESSION" then prophet explained to how to treat them etc.
Why no sunnah mentions it: maybe it was given and understood by everyone, you can't forcefully have physical relationship. Report here mention slave forced himself upon the female and he was punished for commiting zina. This report mentioned by Imam malik proves it. Of course sahaba not going to do something that prophet didn't teach them. Specially when comes giving punishments. Cuz if you punish someone innocent then you can held accountable in day of judgment.
So from the action of the sahaba (may Allah be pleased with them all) we know it's part of the sunnah.
In authentic hadith prophet peace and blessing be upon him said:
I enjoin you to fear Allah, and to listen and obey, even if an Abyssinian slave is appointed over you. For indeed, whoever among you lives long will see much difference. So stick to my Sunnah and the Sunnah of the rightly guided Caliphs, hold onto it and bite onto it with your molars. And beware of newly invented matters, for every newly invented matter is an innovation, and every innovation is a misguidance. (Sunan Abi Dawud 4607)
And in another hadith:
Verily, I do not know how much longer I will remain with you. After me, follow these two,” and the Prophet pointed to Abu Bakr and Umar.
Source: Sunan al-Tirmidhī 3663
Point is if this is action of Umar ibn Khatab (may Allah be please with him) then it's part of sunnah and we follow it.
